# R ggplot - box plot in generalzied function

Tags: r, ggplot2

With `ggplot` I'm trying to make a custom function to plot `boxplot` for a single column in a `dataframe` such that it can be used with any `dataframe`

**Specific Example**

```
male = data.frame(male = c(127,44,28,83,0,6,78,6,5,213,73,20,214,28,11)) # data from 
ggplot(data = male, aes(x = "", y = male)) + geom_boxplot() +
  stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="point", shape=20, size=2, color="red", fill="red")
```

This gives the expected boxplot with the `mean` shown as a point.

[image]

**Generalized function** - here the operation done in the specific example is wrapped into a generalized function

```
boxPlotFn = function (df, colName) {
  ggplot(data = df, aes_string(x = "", y = colName)) + geom_boxplot() + 
    stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="point", shape=20, size=2, color="red", fill="red")
}
```

And I call the function like below

```
boxPlotFn(male, "male")
```

However, this gives the error `Error: No expression to parse` - `rlang::last_error()` indicates that the error is happening at the call to `ggplot`. What am I not doing right here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a bit tricky but easily solved. To make your function work with `aes_string` you have to quote the "double quotes" mapped on `x` using e.g. single quotes. Additionally it should probably be `data = df` inside your function:

```r
library(ggplot2)

male = data.frame(male = c(127,44,28,83,0,6,78,6,5,213,73,20,214,28,11)) # data from 

boxPlotFn = function (df, colName) {
  ggplot(data = df, aes_string(x = '""', y = colName)) + 
    geom_boxplot() + 
    stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="point", shape=20, size=2, color="red", fill="red")
}

boxPlotFn(male, "male")
```

[image]